# Retrieve past Android Wear Crashes/Exceptions

Tags: wear-os, crash-reports

My Wear Watchface occasionally crashes (App has stopped message on my Moto 360). This happens when I'm not around a PC to check the current logs through ADB.

Is there any way to automatically save log files when a crash occurs on Android Wear, and to retrieve the log files later?